# How can I produce this R plot with Sas

Tags: r, sas

**In the mean while, I worked my way around it, my solution is below. Please let me know if you know better methods**

I would like to produce the following regression plot in SAS:

[image]

The dots are the experiment results, blue dots are males, red dots are females. The black line is a simple regression fit through all of the dots. The dashed lines are made with a regression model with the predictor gender included (no interaction term), like Y=alpha + beta_1.X_1i + beta_2.X_2i with beta_2i the dummy variable for gender. The red dashed line is the regression of this model for females, the blue is the regression model for males.

This is the SAS code I am using now to get the regression parameters, which give me already the same result as in R:

```
PROC REG DATA= datasalary;
MODEL Salary=Yearsemployed gender / CLB R DW DWPROB;
OUTPUT out=pred p=Yhat RSTUDENT=Residuals L95M=Low U95M=High ;;
RUN;
```

Any ideas how to make the plot in Sas?
Thanks in advance!
Kasper

**Solution, quite cumbersome, so maybe there are easier ways**

[image]

I did this by outputting the regression coefficients to a global parameter, and later using that global parameter in the SGPlot procedure.

```
PROC REG DATA= datasalary outest=est_model2;
MODEL Salary=Yearsemployed gender / CLB R DW DWPROB;
OUTPUT out=pred p=Yhat RSTUDENT=Residuals L95M=Low U95M=High;
RUN;

%LET model2_alpha = 0;
%LET model2_beta1 = 0;
%LET model2_beta2 = 0;

Data _null_;
Set est_model2;
 call symput("model2_alpha",Intercept);
 call symput("model2_beta1",Yearsemployed);
 call symput("model2_beta2",Gender);
 call symput("model_2_intercept_males", Intercept + Gender);
Run;
%put &model2_alpha;
%put &model2_beta1;
%put &model2_beta2;
%put &model_2_intercept_males;

PROC SGPlot Data = datasalary;
    Scatter X=Yearsemployed Y=Salary / Group = Gender;
    Lineparm x=0 y=&model1_alpha slope=&model1_beta1 / LINEATTRS=(Color= "Black");
    Lineparm x=0 y=&model2_alpha slope=&model2_beta1 / LINEATTRS=(Color= "Maroon" Pattern= MediumDash);
    Lineparm x=0 y=&model_2_intercept_males  slope=&model2_beta1 / LINEATTRS=(Color= "VIB   " Pattern= MediumDash);
    XAXIS LABEL = 'Salary' VALUES = (0 TO 30 BY 5);
    YAXIS LABEL = 'Years experience' VALUES = (0 TO 35 BY 5);
    TITLE 'Linear regression with two predictors and no interaction terms';
 Run;
```

Comment: You can use the REG statement in SGPlot, but I don't think it can handle dummy variables or general multivariate regression.  What you are doing is probably the best way to achieve what you are looking for. You can use the `NOAUTOLEGEND` option on the `PROC SGPLOT` statement to remove the legend.

Comment: I agree, a lot of code, but the solution isn't much optimizable.

Answer (score 0):

@DomPazz and @Astro are correct, what you're trying to do won't come directly from SGPLOT, nor will it come directly from PROC REG. While PROC REG does have some plotting capabilities, it can't plot multiple models on the same graph (at least as of v9.4). Your workaround is reasonable, but you can add a couple of things to make the plot more closely resemble that from R, specifically `grid` options in the axis statements.

```
proc reg data = datasalary outest = est_model2;
    model salary = yearsemployed gender / clb r dw dwprob;
    output out=pred p=yhat rstudent=residuals l95m=low u95m=high;
run;
quit;

data _null_;
    set est_model2;
    call symputx('model2_beta0', intercept);
    call symputx('model2_beta1', yearsemployed);
    call symputx('model2_beta2', gender);
    call symputx('model2_intercept_males', intercept+gender);
run;

title 'Linear regression with two predictors and no interaction terms';

proc sgplot data = datasalary noautolegend;
    reg x = yearsemployed y = salary /
        group = gender
        lineattrs = (color=black pattern=solid);
    lineparm x = 0 y = &model2_beta0 slope = &model2_beta1 /
        lineattrs = (color=red pattern=mediumdash);
    lineparm x = 0 y = &model2_intercept_males slope = &model2_beta1 /
        lineattrs = (color=blue pattern=mediumdash);
    xaxis label = 'Salary' values = (0 to 30 by 5)
        grid gridattrs = (color=gray pattern=shortdash);
    yaxis label = 'Years Experience' values = (0 to 35 by 5)
        grid gridattrs = (color=gray pattern=shortdash);
run;

title;
```

Here I'm assuming that model1 in your code refers to a simple linear regression model containing only the intercept and `yearsemployed`. In that case you can use the REG statement to get the scatter plot and the regression line for that model. Note that the REG statement in SGPLOT only supports simple linear regression models.